# Concatenating values in a print statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, output, string-concatenation

I have the string "Bob" stored in a variable called `name`.

I want to print this:

```
Hello Bob
```

How do I get that?

---

Let's say I have the code

```
name = "Bob"
print ("Hello", name)
```

This gives

```
('Hello', 'Bob')
```

Which I don't want.
If I put in the code

```
name = "Bob"
print "Hello"
print name
```

This gives

```
Hello
Bob
```

Which is also not what I want. I just want plain old

```
Hello Bob
```

How do I get that?

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate or dumb question.

Comment: `print ("Hello" +" "+ name)`

Comment: @RafaelCardoso, python 2 -  I am using the online compiler repl.it

Comment: See https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Is this a bad question? If so, I can delete it. Thanks to all for their answers!

Comment: Well. its a *very* basic Python question :)

Comment: @Bart, well, to be honest, I'm a pretty "basic" user, I haven't done too much in Python. =) Is it too basic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it's printing unexpectedly is because in Python 2.x, print is a statement, not function, and the parentheses and space are creating a tuple. Print can take parentheses like in Python 3.x, but the problem is the space between the statement and parentheses. The space makes Python interpret it as a tuple. Try the following:

```
print "Hello ", name
```

Notice the missing parentheses. `print` isn't a function that's called, it's a statement. It prints `Hello Bob` because the first string is and the variable separated by the comma is appended or concatenated to the string that is then printed. There are many other ways to do this in Python 2.x.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helps explain the solution better.

Comment: Also note that the space between the print statement in and the parentheses effected the outcome. Without the space it should work fine

Comment: FWIW, I was planning on accepting the answer; I was just waiting for the 9 minutes to be up. =) Also, good to know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 14):

There are several ways to archive this:

**Python 2:**

```
>>> name = "Bob"
>>> print("Hello", name)
Hello Bob
>>> print("Hello %s" % name)
Hello Bob
```

**Python 3:**

```
>>> name = "Bob"
>>> print("Hello {0}".format(name))
Hello Bob
```

**Both:**

```
>>> name = "Bob"
>>> print("Hello " + name)
Hello Bob
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x, you can print out directly

```
print "Hello", name
```

But you can also format your string

```
print ("Hello %s" % name)
print "Hello {0}".format(name)
```

Comment: I thought that `"{}".format()` was the standard in Python3?

Comment: Formatting using the percent character is deprecated in Python 3. It was replaced by the ``str.format()`` method.

Comment: @Bart I was just editing

Answer (score 1):

Replace your comma (`,`) with a plus sign (`+`), and add some appropriate spacing.

**Code**

```
name = "Bob"
print("Hello " + name)
```

**Output**

```
Hello Bob
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Hello" + ' ' + name)
```

should do it on python 2

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the difference between Python 2 and Python 3.  In Python 2, the `print` is a statement and doesn't need parentheses. By adding parentheses you end up creating a tuple, which doesn't print the way you want. Simply take out the parentheses.

```
print "Hello", name
```

Often you won't see this effect because you're only printing one item; putting parentheses around a *single* item *doesn't* create a tuple.  The following would work the same in Python 2 and Python 3:

```
print(name)
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer explains why the solution works.